# Nginx location directive and php scripts

Tags: nginx

I have an issue with an Nginx location directive. I need to be able to send any URI through fastcgi so that it ends up in a PHP framework. But I also want to set up a rule whereby any URI beginning with /users gets redirected (let's say to http://www.google.com). So this is how I'm doing it:

```
    location ~* ^/users*$ {
            rewrite ^ http://www.google.com? permanent;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on; # to support 404s for PHP files not found
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I can go to any URL and it will send it through the PHP framework I am using, so that part works. However, the /users* redirect does not work. If I comment out the second location direction (for the PHP files), the /users* redirect works, but it actually downloads the index.php as a file before redirecting to http://www.google.com.

How can I get this to work as intended?

Answer (score 1):

The regex `^/users*$` probably doesn't match what you expect it to match.  Something like `^/users.*$` or `^/users` will be much more inclusive.

Comment: As I said, it works if you comment out the second location directive, so there's nothing wrong with the syntax. It's more just an issue with ordering/priority of directives in general.